# Flatten a 2d array while preserving numeric associative row keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, flatten

I need to flatten a 2d array to become a 1d array without losing my numeric 2nd level keys in the process.

Sample data:

```
[
    [2015 => '2015'],
    [2016 => '2016'],
    [2017 => '2017'],
    [2018 => '2018'],
    [2019 => '2019'],
    [2020 => '2020'],
    [2021 => '2021'],
    [2022 => '2022'],
    [2023 => '2023']
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
    2015 => '2015',
    2016 => '2016',
    2017 => '2017',
    2018 => '2018',
    2019 => '2019',
    2020 => '2020',
    2021 => '2021',
    2022 => '2022',
    2023 => '2023'
]
```

Is it possible to get output like this?

Comment: It is but wouldnt `[2015,2016,2017,.....]` be simpler to deal with

Comment: Yes but array must be sorted like this way

Comment: Or `['2015','2016','2017',.....]` is you actually want the numbers as text

Comment: Well sorting a flat array of numbers is simple `sort($theArray);`

Comment: How do you mean? sort function returns only boolean?

Comment: `sort()` sorts the array it is passed, it does not return a new sorted array

Comment: `iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($years)))` as shown on [this answer on "How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35065033/2943403) will do the job in one functional line of code and preserve the associative numeric keys.  Proof: https://3v4l.org/9rEm4

Comment: [this answer on the dupe page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61557517/2943403) also serves the needs of this new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do simple foreach loop:

```
<?php

$years = array(
    array(2015 => '2015'),
    array(2016 => '2016'),
    array(2017 => '2017'),
    array(2018 => '2018'),
    array(2019 => '2019'),
    array(2020 => '2020'),
    array(2021 => '2021'),
    array(2022 => '2022'),
    array(2023 => '2023')
);

foreach($years as $year) {
    $key = key($year);
    $value = current($year);
    $result[$key] = $value;
}

var_dump($result);
```

**Output:**

```
$result = [
    2015 => '2015',
    2016 => '2016',
    2017 => '2017',
    2018 => '2018',
    2019 => '2019',
    2020 => '2020',
    2021 => '2021',
    2022 => '2022',
    2023 => '2023'
];
```

Comment: The `$value` declaration is not needed because `$result[$key] = $year[$key];`.  This change would eliminate a function call on every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
$theArray = [ 
    [2020 => '2020'], [2021 => '2021'], [2022 => '2022'], [2023 => '2023'],
    [2015 => '2015'], [2016 => '2016'], [2017 => '2017'], [2018 => '2018'], [2019 => '2019']
];

$new = [];
foreach ( $theArray as $a) {
    $new[key($a)] = $a[key($a)];
}
ksort($new);
print_r($new);
```

RESULTS

```
Array
(
    [2015] => 2015
    [2016] => 2016
    [2017] => 2017
    [2018] => 2018
    [2019] => 2019
    [2020] => 2020
    [2021] => 2021
    [2022] => 2022
    [2023] => 2023
)
```

> Of course, it might be more efficient to go to the code that created your original array and amend that to create what you want rather than what it currently does.

Comment: array_keys function assigns key values to new array and that is ok.

But  instead automaticaly generated indexes of array i need: 


Array
(
    2015 => 2015
    2016 => 2016
)

Comment: Why, its just duplication of the year, why do you need that

Comment: Were you really just asking how you could sort the original array?

Comment: Because i need array in that format, it will act as enum fields

Comment: If the value from `key()` is cached as a variable,  you won't need to call it twice during each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I originally closed this page with this canonical page: [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1319903/2943403) After consulting with a moderator, it was advised that this question with narrower requirements should be reopened instead of clarifying the behavior of each answer on the other page which contains a mixture of viable and non-viable solutions for this question.

Here is a rather comprehensive list of viable techniques:

---

`array_reduce()` using the union operator with PHP7.4's arrow function syntax generates no variables in the global scope. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/HbKLQ))

```
var_export(
    array_reduce($array, fn($result, $row) => $result + $row, [])
);
```

---

`array_reduce()` using `array_replace()` with PHP7.4's arrow function syntax generates no variables in the global scope. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jCebV))

```
var_export(
    array_reduce($array, fn($result, $row) => array_replace($result, $row), [])
);
```

---

Converting the data from recursive iterator methods to an array generates no variables in the global scope. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/JQksc)

```
var_export(
    iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)))
);
```

---

`array_walk()` requires a global variable to be declared and it is modified by reference in the closure and calls `key()`. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/M81aW)

```
$result = [];
array_walk($years, function($row) use(&$result) { $k = key($row); $result[$k] = $row[$k]; });
var_export($result);
```

---

`array_walk_recursive()` requires a global variable to be declared and it is modified by reference in the closure without calling `key()`. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/TQodA)

```
$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($years, function($v, $k) use (&$result) { $result[$k] = $v; });
var_export($result);
```

---

Nested `foreach()` loops generate multiple variables in the global scope, but call no functions. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/rDM0f)

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
        $result[$k] = $v;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

---

There are other viable approaches that use manually scripted recursion and generators but they are less attractive in terms of readability and are likely to be overkill for this task (in my opinion).

---

Now for the approaches that must not be used because they lose the numeric associative keys in the rows.  DON'T use these flattening techniques for this question's data set / requirements.

- [`var_export(array_merge(...$array));`](https://3v4l.org/KcVZd)
- [`var_export(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array));`](https://3v4l.org/4gXDS)
- [`var_export(array_reduce($array, 'array_merge', \[\]));`](https://3v4l.org/rdkhp)

Laravel's `Arr::flatten()` method [implements manually written recursive code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/99263998eb4e4b5cd0d536737c00cb4ba5f36ff0/src/Illuminate/Collections/Arr.php#L233) which returns a flat, indexed array -- not appropriate for this case.

Ouzo goodies's `Array::flatten()` method [uses `array_walk_recursive()`](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies/blob/04825afbcf5169b8b819aa4b994d41eb80c93304/Utilities/Arrays.php) to return a flat, indexed array -- not appropriate for this case.